# How to use shared memory with python multiprocessing on android (kivy)?

Tags: python, android, multiprocessing, kivy

In an android kivy app I need to make some heavy computations that do not release GIL. I'd like the app to remain responsive. I also need to be able to cancel the operation. The obvious choice seems to run it in a separate process and use shared memory for the cancel flag. But it does not work since android does not have /dev/shm. Is there a way to get hold of android's shared memory from python?

Comment: maybe you use `queue` instead of shared memory?

Comment: Possibly you can just use the android api to get shared memory via pyjnius, then access it in python.

Comment: I see... It is a little confusing that some parts of the multiprocessing mudule work fine, while others don't.